# How to fetch data in weather API on Redux with parameters?

Tags: javascript, redux, axios, openweathermap

My question is simple as how can I get city and country, on axios fetch  with multiple parameters on URL with Redux?

In the `ROOT_URL` the parameters are `city` and `country` change:

```
const URL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`;
```

My **actions**

```
import axios from 'axios';
const API_KEY = "a3de5cffde10c377d199699b3da6fc6f";

export function getWeather (city, country) { 
    const URL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city},${country}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`;
    
    return(dispatch)=>{
        return axios.get(URL)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch(changeWeather(res));
        }).catch(err =>{
            console.log('error', err);
        });
      
    }
}
const changeWeather = weather => ({
    type: 'CHANGE_WEATHER',
    weather
});
```

The **reducers**

```
const weatherDefaultState = {
    city:undefined, 
    country:undefined, 
    
};
export default (state=weatherDefaultState,action)=>{
    switch(action.type) { 
        case 'CHANGE_WEATHER':
        return {...state, weather: action.weather}
        default: return state;
    }
};
```

and the component with **redux**, runs but the button does not perform any action, what is the error?

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { getWeather } from '../actions/weather';
class Weather extends React.Component {
    
    loadWeather = () => { 
        const API_KEY = 'a3de5cffde10c377d199699b3da6fc6f';
        const URL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Merida,mx&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`;
        
        return(dispatch)=>{
            return axios.get(URL)
            .then(res => {
                dispatch(getWeather(res));
            }).catch(err =>{
                console.log('error', err);
            });
          
        }
    }
    render() {
        return(<div>
            <WeatherForm
                 weather={this.props.weather}
                 handleClick={this.loadWeather}
            />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class WeatherForm extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(<div>
            <button
            className='boton-color'
            style={{backgroundColor:'darkcyan'}}
            onClick={()=>{this.props.handleClick() }} 
            type="button" >
            <p 
            className="card-text-correo"> 
            clima </p></button>
            </div>)
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return state
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Weather);
```

Comment: First of all I noticed you have `loadWeather` in the component doing the same thing as `getWeather` in the function but trying to dispatch an unknown action `obtieneClima`. The whole point of having your actions is to delegate this functionality to them and remove it from the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, you don't make HTTP call at all. 
Inside your `loadWeather` function, which is just method on the component, you return a function which takes `dispatch` as an argument, this isn't correct. 
You have your async action, which is great ( I assume you have installed and connected [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) properly.

So, you need to get access to this action inside your component. This should be made using `connect` module which you installed and connected. But it also takes another parameter to connect actions to props.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return state
};

/* This one you should add */
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
   return {
      getWeatherDispatch: (city, country) => {
          dispatch(getWeather(city, country))
      }
   }
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Weather);
```

As a result, you can invoke your action inside a component using `this.props.getWeatherDispatch(yourCity, yourCountry)`

Comment: From the [docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api/connect.md#mapstatetoprops-state-ownprops--object): "If you don't want to subscribe to store updates, pass `null` or `undefined` in place of `mapStateToProps`."